# Pandas str.contains, containing all the given characters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, contains

Is it possible to search strings that contain all the given characters with str.contain?

This works:

```
df["col1"].str.contains("A")
```

If I want to find atleast one of the given characters, this one works too:

```
df["col1"].str.contains("A|B")
```

However if I want to find strings that contains all the given characters, this doesn't work

```
df["col1"].str.contains("A&B")
```

It results all-false.

Any advices?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

either

```
df['col1'].str.contains('A.*B|B.*A')
```

or

```
df['col1'].str.contains('A') & df['col1'].str.contains('B')
```

example:

```
>>> df
      col1
0  wAxyzBw
1  wBxyzAw
2    wAxyz
3    wBxyz
>>> df['col1'].str.contains('A.*B|B.*A')
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: col1, dtype: bool
>>> df['col1'].str.contains('A') & df['col1'].str.contains('B')
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: col1, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 4):

Another approach:

```
df['col1'].apply(set('AB').issubset)
```

And some example timings:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

strings = pd.Series(['A', 'B', 'C', 'Aaba', 'Baca', 'CABA', 'dog', 'cat'])
%timeit strings.apply(set('AB').issubset)
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 102 µs per loop
%timeit strings.str.contains('A.*B|B.*A')
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 149 µs per loop
%timeit strings.str.contains('A') & strings.str.contains('B')
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 712 µs per loop
```

Comment: Nicely done! One of the fun things about being on here is learning other (better) approaches to a problem.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more general way to do this if you're looking for a large (or initially unknown) set of characters is

```
DataFrame({key: df.col1.str.contains(key) for key in 'AB'}).all(axis=1)
```

There may be better ways to do this (usually are in pandas :), but it gave me comparable performance to **@benzad.nouri**'s answer on a 5mm row DF.